# NoReverseMatch in Django 2

Tags: django, django-views

I'm kinda new at this, and I believe I have misunderstood some things so I'll try to describe it as best possible.

I have 3 tables(models), Game, Chapter, Thread.
Chapter and Thread are connected with the Game table.

**models.py**

```
class Game(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

class Chapter(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=80)
    content = models.CharField(max_length=10000, null=True)
    game = models.ForeignKey(Game, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.chapter

class Thread(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    content = models.CharField(max_length=1000, null=True)
    game = models.ForeignKey(Game, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

**views.py**

```
def chapter(request, game_id):
    auth = top_menu = True
    chapters = Chapter.objects.filter(game=game_id)
    return render(request, 'chapters.html', {"chapters": chapters, "auth": auth, "top_menu": top_menu})

def thread(request, game_id):
    auth = top_menu =True
    threads = Thread.objects.filter(game=game_id)
    return render(request, 'threads.html', {"auth": auth, "threads": threads, "top_menu": top_menu})
```

**urls.py**

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('', index, name="index"),
    path('signup/', signup, name="signup"),
    path('logout/', logout_view, name="logout"),
    path('login/', login_view, name="login"),
    path('<int:game_id>/chapters/', chapter, name="chapter"),
    path('<int:game_id>/threads/', thread, name="thread"),
]
```

**index.html**

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}

{% block content %}
    <div class="container">
        <div class="wrapper">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-lg-12 text-center" style="margin-bottom:80px;">
                    <h1>Welcome to Solo Rpg Helper</h1>
                </div>
            </div>
            {% if auth %}
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-lg-12 text-center">
                    <h1>Your games:</h1>
                    <ul class="list-group list-group-flush">
                        {% for game in games.all %}
                            <a href="{% url 'chapter' game.id %}"><li class="list-group-item">{{ game.title }}</li></a>
                        {% endfor %}
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
            {% else %}
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-lg-12 text-center sign-buttons">
                    <h3><a href="{% url 'login' %}" class="btn btn-lg btn-success">Sign in</a> <a href="{% url 'signup' %}" class="btn btn-lg btn-danger">Sign up</a></h3>
                </div>
            </div>
            {% endif %}
        </div>
    </div>
{% endblock %}
```

**chapter.html**

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}

{% block top_menu %}
    <li><a href="{% url 'index' %}">Games</a></li>
    <li><a href="{% url 'chapter' 1 %}">Chapters</a></li>
    <li><a href="{% url 'thread' 1 %}">Threads</a></li>
{% endblock %}
{% block content %}
    <div class="container">
        <div class="wrapper">
            {% for chapter in chapters.all %}
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-lg-6">
                        <h1>{{ chapter.title }}</h1>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-lg-6">
                        <p>{{ chapter.content }}</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            {% endfor %}
        </div>
    </div>
{% endblock %}
```

*index.html* works fine because I loop the games so I can access game.id.

In the *chapter.html* I want to use again game.id but I'm not sure how to access it although it is passed in the function chapter in the *views.py* (I can see it in the terminal).

If I use it like this:

```
<li><a href="{% url 'chapter' 1 %}">Chapters</a></li>
```

it works, but if I use game.id as in *index.html*:

```
<li><a href="{% url 'chapter' game.id %}">Chapters</a></li>
```

I get the error:

[image: Error:]

I'm sorry for the long post.

Comment: Where is the `games` variable coming from in `for game in games.all`?

Comment: You can shorten your answer by removing the unrelated code. The error is coming from the `chapter` url, so it would be enough to show the URL patterns, `chapter` view, and `chapters.html`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
def chapter(request, game_id):
    auth = top_menu = True
    chapters = Chapter.objects.filter(game=game_id)
    return render(request, 'chapters.html', {"chapters": chapters, "auth": auth, "top_menu": top_menu})
```

You can't use `game.id` in the `chapters.html` template at the moment, because the view doesn't include `game` in the context dictionary.

A typical approach is to use `get_object_or_404`, to handle the case when no game matches `game_id`.

```
from django.shortcuts import get_object_or_404

def chapter(request, game_id):
    auth = top_menu = True
    game = get_object_or_404(Game, pk=game_id)
    chapters = Chapter.objects.filter(game=game_id)
    return render(request, 'chapters.html', {"chapters": chapters, "auth": auth, "top_menu": top_menu, "game": game})
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I had thought of that at some time but did it completely wrong. Your code worked like a charm!